# Get declarations from an external source in Xtext

Tags: xtext

I have the following grammar:

```
Model: declarations += Declaration* statements += Statement*;
Declaration: 'Declare' name=ID;
Statement: 'Execute' what=[Declaration];
```

With that I can write simple scripts like:

```
Declare step_forward
Declare turn_right
Declare turn_left

Execute step_forward
Execute turn_left
Execute step_forward
```

Now I want that the java program provides all declarations, so that the script only contains the `Execute` statements. I read about `IGlobalScopeProvider` which seems to be the right tool for the job, but I have no idea how to add my data to it, and how to make Xtext use it.

So, how can I provide declarations from external to my grammar?

**Update**

My goal was somewhat unclear, so I try to make it more concrete. I want to keep the declarations as simple java objects, for instance:

```
List<Move> declarations = Arrays.asList(
    new Move("step_forward"),
    new Move("turn_right"),
    new Move("turn_left"));
```

and the script should be:

```
Execute step_forward
Execute turn_left
Execute step_forward
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not really sure what you are asking for. After thinking about it, I cand derive th following possible questions:

1.) You want to split your script into two files. File a will only contain your declarations and File b then will only contain Statements. But any 'what' attribute will hold a reference to the declarations of File a.

This works out of the box with your grammar.

2.) You have any Java source code which provides a class which defines, for example a 'Declare Interface', and you want the 'what' attribute to reference to this interface or to classes which implement this interface.

**Updated answer** You should use Xbase within your language. There you can define that your 'what' attribute references to any Java type using the Xtypes rule 'JvmTypeReference'. The modifications you have to within your grammar are not that difficult, I think it could look this:

```
// Grammar now inherits from the Xbase grammar 
// instead of the common terminals grammar
grammar org.xtext.example.mydsl.MyDsl with org.eclipse.xtext.xbase.Xbase

generate myDsl "http://www.xtext.org/example/mydsl/MyDsl"

Model:
    declarator=Declarator?
    statements+=Statement*;

Declarator:
    'Declare' name=ID;

Statement:
    'Execute' what=JvmTypeReference;
```

The, you can refer to any Java type (Java API, any linked API, user-defined types) by adressing them with their qualified name. It would look like this:
[Referring to JVM types look like this in an Xtext language. (Screenshot)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vIHPJ.png)

You can also validate whether the referenced JVM type is valid, e.g. implements a desired interface which I would define with one single, optional declarator in the model. 
[Referenced JVM type is checked whether it is a valid type. (Screenshot)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y8p7z.png)

With Xbase it is very easy to infer a Java interface for this model element. Use the generated stub '...mydsl.MyDslJvmModelInferrer':

```
class MyDslJvmModelInferrer extends AbstractModelInferrer {

    @Inject extension JvmTypesBuilder
    @Inject extension TypeReferences
    def dispatch void infer(Model element, IJvmDeclaredTypeAcceptor acceptor, boolean isPreIndexingPhase) {
        acceptor.accept(
            element.declaration.toInterface('declarator.' + element.declaration.name) [
                members += it.toMethod("execute", TypesFactory.eINSTANCE.createJvmVoid.createTypeRef)[]
            ])
    }
}
```

It derives a single interface, named individually with only one method 'execute()'.

Then, implement static checks like this, you should use the generated stub '...mydsl.validation.MyDslValidator' In my example it is very quick and dirty, but you should get the idea of it:

```
class MyDslValidator extends AbstractMyDslValidator {

    @Check
    def checkReferredType(Statement s) {
        val declarator = (s.eContainer as Model).declaration.name
        for (st : (s.what.type as JvmDeclaredType).superTypes) {
            if (st.qualifiedName.equals('declarator.' + declarator)) {
                return
            }
        }
        (s.what.simpleName + " doesn't implement the declarator interface " + declarator).
            warning(MyDslPackage.eINSTANCE.statement_What)
    }
}
```

(I used the preferred Xtend programming language to implement the static checking!) The static check determines if the given JvmTypeReference (which is a Java class from your project) implements the declared interface. Otherwise it will introduce a warning to your dsl document.

Hopefully this will answer your question.

**Next update:** Your idea will not work that well! You could simply write a template with Xtend for that without using Xbase, but I cannot imagine how to use it in a good way. The problem is, I assume, you don't to generate the hole class 'Move' and the hole execution process. I have played around a little bit trying to generate usable code and seems to be hacky! Neverthess, here is my solution:

Xtext generated the stub '...mydsl.generator.MyDslGenerator' for you with the method 'void doGenerate'. You have to fill this method. My idea is the following: First, you generate an abstract and generic Executor class with two generic parameters T and U. My executor class then has an abstract method 'executeMoves()' with the return value T. If this should be void use the non-primitive 'Void' class. It holds your List, but of the generic type u which is defined as a subclass of a Move class.

The Move class will be generated, too, but only with a field to store the String. It then has to be derived. My 'MyDslGenerator' looks like that:

```
class MyDslGenerator implements IGenerator {
    static var cnt = 0
    override void doGenerate(Resource resource, IFileSystemAccess fsa) {
        cnt = 0
        resource.allContents.filter(typeof(Model)).forEach [ m |
            fsa.generateFile('mydsl/execution/Move.java', generateMove)
            fsa.generateFile('mydsl/execution/Executor' + cnt++ + '.java', m.generateExecutor)
        ]
    }

    def generateMove() '''
        package mydsl.execution;
        public class Move {
            protected String s;
            public Move(String s) {
                this.s = s;
            }
        }
    '''

    def generateExecutor(Model m) '''
        package mydsl.execution;
        import java.util.List;
        import java.util.Arrays;
        /**
         * The class Executor is abstract because the execution has to implemented somewhere else.
         * The class Executor is generic because one does not know if the execution has a return
         * value. If it has no return value, use the not primitive type 'Void':
         * public class MyExecutor extends Executor_i<Void> {...}
         */
        public abstract class Executor«cnt - 1»<T, U extends Move> {
            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            private List<U> declarations = Arrays.<U>asList(
                «FOR Statement s : m.statements»
                    (U) new Move("«s.what.name»")«IF !m.statements.get(m.statements.size - 1).equals(s)»,«ENDIF»
                «ENDFOR»
            );
            /**
             * This method return list of moves.
             */
            public List<U> getMoves() {
                return declarations;
            }
            /**
             * The executor class has to be extended and the extending class has to implement this
             * method.
             */
            public abstract T executeMoves();
        }'''
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your detailed answer; but as you mentioned, my question was unclear. Just updated the question. My language will have nothing to with Java/JVM. Does it make sense to use Xbase then?

Comment: If you only want to generate a simple list from the execute statements, you don't need Xbase. Xbase normally is used if you want to refer to JVMTypes or you need some expressions in your language. Look at the answer how to create Java code like you want, I have updated it.